# Proving $\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:|x|^2+|y|<1\}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:|x|^2+|y|<1\}$. How to show $A$ is convex.

Starting with $(x,y), (a,b)\in A$ and $t\in [0,1]$, we need to show $(tx+(1-t)a,ty+(1-t)b)$. For this we need to consider $|tx+(1-t)a|^2+|ty+(1-t)b|$. Due to first squared term, a term $2t(1-t)|x||a|$ is left out, rest can be made less than $1$, using the definition of the set. That is, I am only able to prove $|tx+(1-t)a|^2+|ty+(1-t)b|<1+2t(1-t)|x||a|,$ but I need to prove $|tx+(1-t)a|^2+|ty+(1-t)b|<1$, in order to prove convexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the obvious simplification: $|x|^2 = x^2$.

So we want to prove that if $x^2+|y|<1$ and $a^2+|b|<1$ then $(t x+(1-t)a)^2 + |ty+(1-t) b| <1$

Consider the two inequalities $$(tx+(1-t)a)^2 \le t x^2 + (1-t)a^2 \tag{1}$$
and $$|ty+(1-t)b|\le t|y|+(1-t)|b| \tag{2}$$

To prove the inequality $(1)$ observe that $$tx^2+(1-t)a^2 - (tx+(1-t)a)^2 = t(1-t)(a-x)^2\ge 0$$

The inequality $(2)$ is just the triangle inequality.

Adding the two inequalities we get $(t x+(1-t)a)^2 + |ty+(1-t) b| \le t(x^2+|y|)+(1-t)(a^2+|b|)< t + (1-t)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align} A=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:|x|^2+|y|<1\} \\
\\
\\= \{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:y<1-x^2\} \cap \{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2}:y>-(1-x^2)\}\\
\\
\end{align}

and both of these sets are convex. Since [the intersection of convex sets is convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Intersections_and_unions), the result follows.